# Python: fnmatchcase in virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to install Flask without success.

I have a virtualenv running in a Bash terminal on Windows 10.

```
$ pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask)
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask)
  Using cached itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\powlo\workspace\proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "c:\users\powlo\workspace\proj\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from fnmatch import fnmatchcase
ImportError: cannot import name 'fnmatchcase'
```

Now, if I run

```
$ winpty python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fnmatch
>>> dir(fnmatch)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__',
'__package__', '__spec__']
```

Nada.

Now if I do the same, but with no virtualenv (that is, using C:\Python35...)

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> dir(fnmatch)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '
__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_compile_pattern', 'filter', 'fnmatch', '
fnmatchcase', 'functools', 'os', 'posixpath', 're', 'translate']
```

So naturally, I can install Flask without the virtualenv. But that's not what I want. Any ideas what's going on?

---

***Update***: So, I can see the fnmatch.py in .venv/Lib/ exists, but is an empty file. If I replace this with the file from C:\Python35\Lib then all is good.

Seems like a bug in virtualenv. Version causing this bug was 15.0.0. I updated to 15.1.0 (via pip install) and fnmatch is correctly copied when creating a virtualenv.

Comment: What's the value of `fnmatch.__file__`?

Comment: @eryksun, value of fnmatch.__file__ is 'C:\\Users\\powlo\\workspace\\proj\\.venv\\lib\\fnmatch.py'

Comment: That shouldn't be there in a typical virtual environment. Do you have other files there that are shadowing the standard library?

Comment: @eryksun Other files in .venv/Lib were present and complete as expected. Either something went weird when the virtualenv was created, or there was a bug in 15.0.0. Fix was to update to 15.1.0. I updated the question with new findings.

Comment: Python 3's venv picks up the standard library from the system, and Lib is mostly empty except for the `site-packages` subdirectory. It's been a while since I used the original virtualenv.